# Bigint Multiplication Help C++

Tags: c++, class, calculator, biginteger

Here I've got a bigint calculator that uses a safearray class(not shown) to store large numbers and do arithmetic operations on them. I've got add and subtract working but when I try multiplication it compiles and runs but nothing happens. Could someone help me fix this? Thanks

```
int size = 100;

class bigint
{
    SafeArray<int> *arr;
public:
    char sign;
bigint()                                                   //initializes to zero
    {
        arr = new SafeArray<int>;
        for(int i =0;i < size; i++)
            arr->set(i,0);
    }

void print()                                               //prints numbers without zeroes in front
    {
        bool start_num=false;
        for(int i = 0;i <arr->get_size() ;i++)
        {
            if(arr->get(i)!=0 && start_num==false )
            {start_num=true;
                cout << arr->get(i);}
         else if(start_num==true)
             cout<<arr->get(i);

        }

       cout<<endl;
    }

void assign(const bigint &A)                             //
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arr->get_size();i++)
        {                                                            //Ways to initialize stuff
            arr->set(i,A.arr->get(i));
        }

    }

void assign(int num)                                     //
    {
        for(int i = arr->get_size()- 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            arr->set(i,num%10);
            num /=10;
        }


    }

void assign(string num)                                  //
    {
        long len = num.length();
        int j=arr->get_size()-1;
        for(long i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            arr->set(j,num[i]-48);
            j--;
        }
    }

void add_pos(const bigint &A)                                //add big ints
    {
        int carry=0;
        for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
           {
               int result = arr->get(i)+A.arr->get(i)+carry;
               arr->set(i,result%10);
               carry=result/10;
           }
    }

    void  multiply(bigint &A)
    {
        bigint temp;


        for(int i=0;i<size;i +=1)
        {
            temp.arr->set(i,arr->get(i));
            arr->set(i,0);
        }
        int i1, i2;
        for(i2=0; i2<size; i2++)
        {
            int borrow =0;
            for(i1=0;i1+i2<size;i1++)
            {
                int total=temp.arr->get(i1)*A.arr->get(i2);
                int totalsum=total+arr->get(i1+i2)+borrow;
                arr->set(i1+i2,totalsum%10);
                borrow = totalsum/10;
            }
        }


};
int main()

{


    bigint a, b, c;
    a.assign("2543281");
    b.assign("3434");
    a.mulitply(b);
    a.print();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger and see what it is doing?

Comment: Have you tried using GDB to see what your program is doing ?

Comment: There is relevant code missing and unneeded code shown in your example.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help improve the quality of this question so that you can get more focused answers as opposed to us helping you "debug" your code. You can debug the code in your IDE.

Comment: I would expect that different values may be associated with different sizes.  Both your addition and multiplication (you haven't shown subtraction) treat all values as having the same size.

Comment: Jack, welcome to SO! While posting code, please format it for pleasant viewing. Also, please mention the problem you are facing, "nothing happens" may not be sufficiently explanatory :).

Answer (score 1):

The result of multiplication of two `bigint` numbers of `size = 100` certainly needs more than `100` digits, perhaps `200`?

For minimal modification, you may pass `size` as constructor argument to `bigint`. Ideally, `bigint` may use a vector so that the digit array can grow dynamically in a convenient and flexible way.

```
class bigint {
  std::vector<int8_t> digits_;   // each digit must be in 0-9 range
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

These were lil complicated so I came up with this:

```
InfInt InfInt::operator*(const InfInt& a) const{

InfInt final = 0;
std::string result;
InfInt* temp;


int carry;
int current;

//fast mult algorithm. the same we were taught in elementary.
for(long i=length() - 1;i >= 0; i--){
    carry = 0;
    result = "";
    for (long j=a.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        current = (value[i] - '0') * (a.value[j] - '0') + carry;
        result = (char)(current % 10 + '0') + result;
        carry = current / 10;
    }

    if (carry > 0)
        result = (char)(carry + '0') + result;

    temp = new InfInt(result);
    final += *new InfInt(temp->alignLeft(length() - i - 1));
}

final.setSign(sign ^ a.sign);
return final;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: How is this related to OP's implementation? It's part of some `InfInt` class, but to run this code you need to define also at least `IntInf::alignLeft` and `IntInf::setSign`

Comment: You're right, even though these are not hard to comprehend. I can't see why it can't help the OP, the algorithm is simple and he/she can convert it to his/her project. But thanks for the help!

following the requested functions:
    InfInt InfInt::alignLeft(const unsigned long l ) const{
    std::string newStr = value;
    for (unsigned long i=0; i<l; i++){
        newStr = newStr + "0";
    }
    return newStr;
    }

    void InfInt::setSign(const bool s){
    sign = s;
    }

Comment: Could you edit your answer and append these functions?